# Installing Anaconda 4.2 on Windows, cannot find "conda"

Tags: python, windows, installation, anaconda, conda

After installing the Anaconda 4.2 package, the quickstart guide tells you to verify your installation using "conda list" and "conda info", but I receive an stdin error duplicated below. This error appears in the cmd console, jupyter notebook, and VS 2015 Community. Below is the problem from the cmd console.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\zalo>python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57)
[MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> conda info
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    conda info
             ^
```

Here is the PATH, which appears to be correct.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Scripts
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\Library\bin

Otherwise, base python seems to be functioning. I've installed and reinstalled Anaconda, Miniconda, 32 and 64-bit versions a dozen times on two different Windows 10 computers. The troubleshooting guide didn't seem to have any steps to take if "conda info" didn't work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2):

`conda` is primarly used as script so you can't start it (easily) from a python interpreter. Just type it in the command line:

```
C:\Users\zalo> conda info
```

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you for helping me clear that up.

Comment: @MSeifert Probably he needs to be told How to accept it. I myself didn't for a long time!!!

Comment: @ThomasSelstad Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that solved your question. :)